# What is the best way to relate different custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Let's say I have 3 CPTs: series, seasons, and episodes.
Now if I post in these custom post types the URL would be:

- Series CPT > post name: sample serie > URL:
  `site.com/series/sample-serie`
- Seasons CPT > post name: sample season > URL:
  `site.com/seasons/sample-season`
- Episodes CPT > post name: sample episode > URL:
  `site.com/episodes/sample-episode`

Now what I want to do is combine these URLs together:

- `site.com/series/sample-serie/sample-season/sample-episode` : To show
  the page for the sample episode (previously:
  `site.com/episodes/sample-episode`)
- `site.com/series/sample-serie/sample-season/` : To show the page for
  the sample season (previously: `site.com/seasons/sample-season`)

How can I implement this? Was creating 3 custom post types a good idea for doing this? Or is there any other methods to do this? (Preferably without any plugins)

Appreciate any further assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better approach for this would be to create a single nested (hierarchical) custom post type.

For example, it can be `series`.

Then a single series named `sample-series` as a top level post of `series` post type: `site.com/series/sample-series/`.

Then seasons named `season-one`, `season-two` etc. can be children of `sample-series`, like: `site.com/series/sample-series/season-one`, `site.com/series/sample-series/season-two`.

Similarly, episodes can be children of those seasons, like: `site.com/series/sample-series/season-one/episode-one`, `site.com/series/sample-series/season-one/episode-two` etc.

Same thing can be done by default by WordPress `page`, since pages are by default hierarchical.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This seems to be a good approach, but one issue with it is that the archive page for the series (`site.com/series`) would also include the seasons and episodes, which is a problem here. I also want separate archive pages for seasons, episodes, and seasons. If this issue can be solved by applying a filter that would be awesome!

Comment: You can customize the template files to achieve that.